# How to plot a list of nodes with relative strength scores in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I would like to represent a collection of interconnected nodes with connection strength on a graph of nodes.

Every node has a matrix of values between 0 and 1 for connection strength to all other nodes, I.E:

```
[1.0000 0.1000 0.1200 0.0010]
[0.1000 1.0000 0.0820 0.0001]
...
```

where the columns represent node strengths and rows nodes.

I want placement of nodes on the graph to be sensible - i.e. a group of strongly connected nodes should be relatively grouped together on the graph.

How would this easiest be done in Matlab? I've seen `gplot` but I'm not sure if it does quite what I'm after.

[image]

Here's an example, simple matrix:

```
strengths=[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.909090909091,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.909090909091,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.909090909091,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.909090909091,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.909090909091,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0.909090909091,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0.909090909091,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0.909090909091,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0.909090909091,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0.909090909091,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.909090909091,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.909090909091,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.909090909091,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.909090909091,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0.909090909091,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0.909090909091,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0.909090909091,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0.909090909091,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0.909090909091,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.909090909091,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.909090909091,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.909090909091,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1.0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.909090909091,1,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

Comment: WOW. I think the "easiest" way will be quite far from easy. Good question though!

Comment: Can you post some data so we can test it? I was going to try with random data, but the graph may look rubbish with that.

Comment: Thanks for having a go, I've put up a simple matrix. Yes, this could be a mammoth task but I'm not after perfection, just something!

Comment: Shouldnt Stregth be symetric? I mean, the stregth of node 1 agaist node 12 shoudl be the same that node 12 against 1, rigth? Or am I understanding wrongly the matrix?

Comment: Yes you're right, I've actually got 2 way strengths in the matrix I put up - so no but in the question I implied symmetry. Either way it shouldn't be a problem? Please feel free to ignore asymmetry.

Comment: Thanks, it was just to make sure I got the thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am showing you my try, but unfortunately I haven't figured it how to define the XY positions of the points depending their distance to others....

However i leave here a piece of code that plots a similar graph of what you want, but instead of the position of the nodes for "strongness" I change the colour of the line between them.

For a more colorful plot you can change the grayscale colour to a colormap (i.e 'jet').

I hope someone else can solve it better!

```
% your stegths are of 1,0.9 or 0 value. I suppose that in general you have
% 0-1 range, so just for this example, i am going to comvert the 0.9 into
% 0.5, so you can see the changes in colour.
strengths(strengths>0&strengths<1)=0.5; 

w=sum(strengths,2);
w=w/max(w);

% I dont have any idea how to do this....
% so I will create random points. Sorry :(
XY=rand(size(strengths,1),2);


isconect=strengths>0;
h=figure
hold on
for ii=1:size(strengths,1)
    plot(XY(ii,1),XY(ii,2),'k.','markersize',50*w(ii))

    for jj=1:sum(isconect(ii,:))-1
        idx=find(isconect(ii,:));
        idx=idx(jj+1);
        wc=strengths(ii,idx);
        plot([XY(ii,1) XY(idx,1)],[XY(ii,2) XY(idx,2)],'color',ones(3,1)*(1-wc),'linewidth',2*wc)
    end
end
set(gcf, 'Color', [1,1,1]);

axis off;
```

[image]

**EDIT:** To avoid lines being plot on top of the circles, just change the order of plotting (i.e. plot the points after the lines). My bad, I just did it in a hurry.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, really helped. I ended up using a model treating nodes as repulsive particles connected by springs with stiffness proportional to strength (then iterate) to calculate the XY coordinates.